# Regex to get part of the string after dot and before hyphen?

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex and have tried to get the regex expression in Python for the following string but still no luck. Just wondering if anyone know the best regex to get **group1** from:

```
test-50.group1-random01.ab.cd.website.com
```

Basically, I was trying to get the part of string **after the first dot and before the second hyphen**

Comment: Use a website like regex101 to build your regex?

Comment: For example, here's azro's answer in regex101: https://regex101.com/r/BrKjMy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do it with `str.split`

```
s = "test-50.group1-random01.ab.cd.website.com"
after_first_dot = s.split(".", maxsplit=1)[1]
before_hyphen   = after_first_dot.split("-")[0]
print(before_hyphen)  # group1
```

---

With a regex, take what is between dot and hyphen

```
result = re.search(r"\.(.*?)-", s).group(1)
print(result)  # group1
```

Comment: @azro Is there a benefit to using search() rather than findall() - e.g., re.findall('\.(.*?)-', s)[0]

Comment: @Lily If you find this answer helpful, the least you can do is accept it, upvote it or both.

Comment: An additional question: In the case of: 
`test-50.group1-random01.ab-cd.website.com`,

_ab_ also starts with a dot and end with a hyphen. Will the regex still work? Looks like it would return both _group1_ and _ab_

Comment: @Lily with `re.findall(r"\.(.*?)-", s)` yes you'll get the both matches,

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to still get _group1_ only? Under either case `test-50.group1-random01.ab.cd.website.com` and `test-50.group1-random01.ab-cd.website.com`

Comment: @Lily with search yes still, of findall then index 0 as proposed LancelotDuLac in his comment